# How to send data using $http GET method in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I need to send emailId as data from angularjs controller to nodejs. I googled it but I didn't get solution, someone please help me.

controller file:

```
function ManageProductController($http, $scope, $mdDialog, $document, $location, $localStorage)
{
     var vm = this;
     vm.email = $localStorage.email;

     $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {email:vm.email}
        }).success(function(res) {
            //$scope.productlist = res;
            //console.log(res.result);
            vm.result=res.result;

            //vm.docs=res.docs;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
}
```

In the above code I have sent `email` as data but in node.js file I am not getting in request.

node file:

```
 router.get('/manage-product', function(req, res){
    //console.log('I received get request');

    console.log(req);
    var findProducts = function(db, callback) {
       var cursor =db.collection('proInfo').find().toArray(function(err, docs){
          if(err){
             callback(new Error("Some problem"));
           }else{
            callback(null,docs);
        } 
         });

    };
}
```

Here I have put `console.log(req);` but in the body section I am getting only `body{}` like this.

Comment: try removing api from your url `http://localhost:7200/manage-product`

Comment: using api its working properly, that's not a problem and my question is how do i send data from angular to node using GET method.

Comment: Should use POST when submitting data to a server.

Comment: @HemanthkumarHJ see my answer with both `GET` and `POST` examples and let know f it works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `GET` you can make use of `params` and at server you can get that value in `req.query` see following sample:

```
 $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {email:vm.email} //at server it will be req.query.email
        }).success(function(res) {

             //access returned res here

        }, function(error) {
            //handle error here
        });
```

With `POST` you can make use of `data` and at server you can get that value in `req.body` see following sample:

```
 $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {email:vm.email} //at server it will be req.body.email
        }).success(function(res) {

             //access returned res here

        }, function(error) {
            //handle error here
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

send data like this below the url with comma

```
url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
method: 'GET',
params: {emailData:yourEmaildata}
```